magento 2.4.5 set checked default checkbox
We have the following module in the vendor extending html
vendor/GB/module-payment

view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

const config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'VndorPayment_Magento2/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc': {
            'GB_Payment/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-mixin': true
        },

in js
js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-mixin

define([], function () {
'use strict';

return function (CreditCard) {
    return CreditCard.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'GB_Payment/payment/cc'
        }
    });
};

});
view/frontend/web/template/payment/cc.html

...
<div class="control">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cc_terms" class="checkbox" value=""
                           data-bind="attr: {
                                                autocomplete: off,
                                                id: getCode() + '_terms',
                                                'data-container': getCode() + '-terms',
                                                'data-validate': JSON.stringify({'validate-terms':'#' + getCode() + '_terms'})
                                            }"/>
                    <span data-bind="html: getTermsHtml()"></span>
                </div>
...

How do I set the checkbox field to default checked?
I tried overriding or via js in cehckout_index_index afterRender and it didn't work

Here you have 2 options.

If you want html tag only, then try this :
<input type="checkbox" name="cc_terms" class="checkbox" Checked>


If you want knowckout code then do like this :
<input id="cc_terms" type="checkbox"  data-bind="checked:Myfunction"/>

Add following code in js file.
var viewModel= {
     Myfunction:ko.observable(true)
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);




This would be simple, but it's in the vendor, and I can't change it, I would have to extend it, but it hasn't worked yet

You need to override the file into custom extension and then apply changes there.

After above changes, you need to run all magento commands and then check.

I can't replace it, I already tried

Then share the compete code which you try for this one

app/code/GB/CheckoutPayment/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Payment_Magento2/js/view/payment/method-renderer/aditumcc': {
            'GB_CheckoutPayment/js/view/payment/method-renderer/aditumcc-mixin': true
        }
    }
}

};
app/code/GB/CheckoutPayment/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/aditumcc-mixin.js
define([
'jquery',
'Payment_Magento2/js/view/payment/method-renderer/aditumcc'

], function ($, AditumCC) {
'use strict';
return function (CreditCard) {
    return CreditCard.extend({
 
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            $('#' + this.getCode() + '_terms').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
};

});
@Dhiren Vasoya
